# Terraform opt in for free- tier cosmosDB account in Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a cosmos database in Azure of kind MongoDB using terraform resources azurerm_cosmosdb_account and azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database . We would like to opt in for the free tier which also doesn't seem to be supported through terraform. Is there a way to acheive this ?

```
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}



resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                = var.cosmosdb_account
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"

  enable_automatic_failover = false

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "Session"
   
  }
  capabilities {
    name = "EnableMongo"
 }

 #geo_location {
 #   location          = var.failover_location
 #   failover_priority = 1
 # }

  geo_location {
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
  
  tags  = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database" "mongo-db" {
  for_each             = var.mongo-databases
  name                 = each.value
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  account_name         = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db.name
  throughput           = 400
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the free tier is only available when you use SQL API. I don't think it's available for any other API.

Comment: It works for all APIs

Comment: Yes it works for all API

Answer (score 3):

Free Tier is supported since [v2.20.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v2.21.0/CHANGELOG.md#2200-july-23-2020) of the AzureRM provider (released on July 21st... Timing...)

See the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/cosmosdb_account.html#enable_free_tier).

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely going to have to make use of the azurerm_template_deployment and create it via an ARM template. I've had to do that for shortcomings on the Azure Service Fabric deployment options that were not at the time in Terraform.

You can separate your arm template into a resource that can be loaded into the body:

```
template_body = file("templates/myarmtemplate.json.tpl)
```

Just be sure to add the depends_on to the dependent components as Terraform won't manage the details of what is deployed within the ARM template but rather monitor whether the deployment succeeded or not.